# MongoDB Add Current Date in aggregation from year month and day

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregation

How can i add a date to document from columns?

i have a documents:

```
{
  day:27,
  month:9,
  year:2023
}
```

and want to get this:

```
{
  date: ISODate("2023-09-27T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Tried to aggregate, but it's not working.

```
db.getCollection('Worker').aggregate([  
    { $addFields:{
        dt: new Date("$year","$month","$day")
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Have you checked out [$dateFromParts](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/)?

Comment: Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help [Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14732669/ray).

```
db.getCollection.aggregate([{ 
    $addFields:{
      date: {$dateFromParts: { 'year' : "$year", 'month' : "$month", 'day': "$days.day"  }}
    }
}])
```